# Calculation of Electric field using centre of mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

One of my Physics teacher told me how to calculate Electric field from centre of mass using Mathematical similarity-

1. Write the Coulomb's law in vector form

$\vec{E}=\frac{K Q}{R^{3}} \vec{R}$

$\vec{\ d E}=\frac{K d Q}{R^{3}} \vec{R}$

$\vec{E}=\frac{K}{R^{3}} \int d Q \vec{R}$

Now mathematical similarity state

$\int d m \vec{R}=m \vec{R}_{c o m}$ &
$\int d q \vec{R}=q \vec{R}_{c o m}$ are equivalent

He also used this method to calculate electric field of a hollow hemispherical shell.
\begin{aligned}
&\vec{E}=\frac{k q}{R^{3}} \overrightarrow{R_{\text {com }}}=\frac{K}{R^{3}} q\left(\frac{R}{2}\right) \\
&\vec{E}=\frac{K q}{2 R^{2}}
\end{aligned}

which is correct and can be proved through integration but the question is Why this method is working as there is no concept of centre of charge?
Is there any textbook or article on this method?

Comment: The calculation seems strange,  in the first equation R is any distance fron Q, later it is the radius of an object?